# overloading operator*

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

In the code below I would like to know what does the operator* overloadind do here.

```
// struct pointer to Shape
struct PtrToShape
{
Shape *ptr;

bool operator < (const PTRToShape & rhs) const
{ return *ptr < *rhs.ptr; }

const Shape & operator*() const
{ return *ptr; }

};
```

What will it overload? Will it overload the * operator for the struct or for the shape objects? Is this overloading used in:

```
return *ptr < *rhs.ptr
```

And in the line I previously mentioned the * (overloaded or not) refers to what? to rhs or to rhs.ptr ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Shape & operator*() const
{ return *ptr; }
```

This returns a reference dereferenced `Shape` object, the one called `ptr`, which is a member of your struct.

That overload will overload this `*operator` for your `PtrToShape` struct.

Also, no, it's not used in `return *ptr < *rhs.ptr`

Comment: so if I got it right *rhs would return the same as *rhs.ptr now that the operator is overloaded for that struct right?

Comment: @user611295 yes that's correct. However I'm not sure if that's necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is a de-reference operator, so that you can de-reference a `PtrToShape` as you would do with a plain pointer to `Shape`.

```
PtrToShape p = ....;
(*p).methodOfShapeClass();
```

It applies to instances of `ShapePtr`, so it does not take part in the comparisons in `operator<`, since in this expression,

```
return *ptr < *rhs.ptr;
```

the RHS is equivalent to `*(rhs.ptr)` due to operator precedence rules.

This is usually accompanied by an `operator->` overload.